# How to periodically retrieve page output and display to user with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a JavaScript newbie and have no idea how to accomplish this, so a push (or shove!) in the right direction would be really great.

I have an HTML page and I need to display some data to a user that is constantly changing. The data is just text output from a web page.

What would be the best way to get the output of a page and then display that output to the user using JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: @mplungjan - Nice! Now I need to find a way to get the output of the web page.

Comment: `var tId = setInterval(function() { location.reload(1) },10000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to load content from another webpage for display on your webpage I would recommend using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('url_here', function(res) {
            $('#result').html(res);
        });
    }, 30000);
});
```

This will load the load entire html response into a div like `<div id="result"></div>` for instance, and will perform this process every 30 seconds (30000 millisconds).

If you need to only display part of the html response you'll need to parse it out of `res` then switch the one line to something like `$('#result').html(myValue);`.

If you need the server to push to the client rather than the client pulling from the server then you probably want a different solution.